# IE is having an issue loading in content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, load

I'm attempting to apply the same method seen at this link on the link below. The first one works in IE but whatever I'm doing fails in in IE. It loads the content but the previous content seems to still exist in the DOM. Additionally some of the styles aren't being applied and I'm not sure why. I can't figure out what I'm messing up.

example-http://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicPage/

http://sandbox.solutionsbydesign.com/seligman-ny/common-questions.php
-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that jQuery with IE doesn't like loading HTML5 elements. When I replaced -section with -div the issues seemed to go away.

Answer (score 0):

Use the load function to load the content from another file into a specified DIV.
http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("div#content").load(page1.html);
```

You can either create multiple javascript functions which load a specific page and use the OnClick event within the a tag or you can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $("a").click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr("id"); // place the name of the page in the ID field within the a tag
    $("div#content").load(page + ".html");
  }
});
```

The div you want to load the page into must be empty. You can load a default page with jquery right after the document ready function.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your script files to header(except google analytics).

Comment: no difference plus => http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom